# Interpreting p-value significance

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, interpretation

If you have performed a statistical test using the standard 95% confidence threshold then a p-value of < 0.05 will indicate significance.

I was reading [a blog post](http://myowelt.blogspot.co.uk/2008/04/beautiful-correlation-tables-in-r.html) about typesetting some correlation data using the `R` library `xtable`. The author uses a series of `ifelse` statements to replace p-values with stars to indicate whether the result was less than `0.001`, `0.01`, or `0.05`. I was wondering if anyone could comment on the validity of this?

If you perform a statistical test at a 95% confidence level and you get a p-value of `< 0.01` does that mean that you could say that the result is significant to the 99% level. Or can you only assume a stronger confidence level if you explicitly performed the test with that criteria?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculation of a p-value does not require any CI to be mentioned. If you have the z-score, you can calculate the p-value by integration over the normal distribution from -inf to the z-score. Or, you could look it up in z-tables.

That's why if you perform a statistical test at a 95% confidence level and you get a p-value of < 0.01 that does mean you could say that the result is significant to the 99% level too.

Comment: Of course! I was forgetting when you perform a test you get back the z-score and then compare it with the value in table. It's been a long time since I've actually done that manually.

Comment: It's actually tough to do manually if we get statistic that follow other distributions. Calculating from z-score is easy though.